# Parse Server beforeSave unset removes field instead of ignoring it

Tags: parse-platform

I'm using Parse Server (community) v3.8. I would like to ignore updates to a certain field of an object, I added the following beforeSave cloud function:

```
async function beforeSave(request) {
    request.object.unset('someField');
    ...
```

But it actually caused its value to be removed during the save rather than ignoring the changes to any existing value.

Any ideas how to block changes to a certain field during save?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the last value from the original object:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('SomeClass', request => {
  if (request.original) {
    request.object.set('someField', request.original.get('someField');
  }
});
```